# Add a button to Android list view

Tags: java, android

I have implemented a simple Android list view using following code.

```
package com.listTester;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ListTestActivity extends ListActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
String[] STOCK = new String[] {...};

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setCacheColorHint(R.drawable.bckimage);
listView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bckimage);
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bckimage);



setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_stock,STOCK));
     . . .
}
}
```

The layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:textSize="20sp"
 android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
</TextView>
```

Now I want to add buttons below to the list elements as shown in the image(This is an edited image).

[image: This is how I want]

How can I do this ??Please help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: create in xml file and use those in this activity..

Comment: you want to add buttons to each list element?
Then you need to define a row.xml and use that in in your listAdapter.

Comment: No I don't need to add buttons to each element. I want to add buttons below to all list elements(as shown in the image).

Comment: put you layout code here. if you want same layout which is in image then its easy. or if you want to add button in each list then use custom adapter and create one more layout which is called row.xml whatever..

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height= "360dp"  
     >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
        <Button
             android:id = "@+id/btn_check"
             android:text="Check Another"
             android:layout_width = "0dp"
             android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="50"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
        <Button
             android:id = "@+id/btn_ok"
             android:text="OK"
             android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
             android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_weight="50"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

fix the listView heigth

Answer (score 1):

You can use merging style for this
You can use http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html link for more knowledge about merge.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:okCancelBar="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.android.merge">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height= "fill_parent"  
     >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_gravity="bottom"

    >
        <Button
             android:id = "@+id/btn_check"
             android:text="Check Another"
             android:layout_width = "0dp"
             android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="50"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
        <Button
             android:id = "@+id/btn_ok"
             android:text="OK"
             android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
             android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_weight="50"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to make them part of the ListView.  Activities containing ListView often don't have an XML layout.  So instantiate a ListFragment in your Activity, and place the buttons below the Fragment in your layout.  Or, alternatively, give the buttons a miss entirely and use ActionBar actions.  It's not obvious what your "OK" button does, but it sort of looks like you could just use "Back" for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain how can I do that ?..I'm new to programming

Comment: it is possible without fragment? i think yes. he is new to programming. why you confusing him???

Comment: @Grant here is a friendly intro to Fragments: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html  Basically, Fragments are like mini-Activities that work together inside a regular Activity to make complex layouts.  They offer extra encapsulation so you can use them separately or together.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use listactivity....use only activity, and put a listview there and add other componants.

Comment: this is suggestion not a perfect answer please comment on question.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use listactivity....use only activity, and add one more layout xml file and add below code into new layout xml file.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mLstView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mLlayout1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mLlayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mBtn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Check Another" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mBtn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mBtn1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="OK" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and Use Custom Adapter.

Comment: Please explain how can I use custom adapter ??

Comment: Please see this link http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in by using `setContentView(R.layout.myxml);`

myxml.xml ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height= "fill_parent"  
     >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
        <Button
             android:id = "@+id/btn1"
             android:text="Check Another"
             android:layout_width = "0dp"
             android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="50"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
        <Button
             android:id = "@+id/btn2"
             android:text="OK"
             android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
             android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_weight="50"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity as modified as per your code. Follow the following xml code...

Code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1">
  </ListView>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />

  </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a footerView. You can do it like this:

```
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setCacheColorHint(R.drawable.bckimage);
listView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bckimage);
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bckimage);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

RelativeLayout bottomButtonsLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_buttons_layout, bottomButtonsLayout, true);
listView .addFooterView(bottomButtonsLayout);

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_stock,STOCK));
```